How to stimulate PSRR of LT3060-2.5 and LT1761-2.5 in LTspice?
I tried following the steps on the analog devices website but it seems that with these components the results are not close to the datasheet while when I try this method with others it works.
Do you know any other way to simulate the PSRR of these two components? I really appreciate your help
Link analog devices I followed: https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/how-to-get-the-best-results-using-ltspice-for-emc-simulation-part-2.html
Here my result:
LT-1761-2.5: 
LT3060-2.5: 

What was the relevance of the link?

I followed the steps and commands according to Analog Devices, which is provided in that link

I think your link is wrong.  You posted a link to Part 2 instead of Part 1.  Anyway, I think you have a divide by zero error for the LT3060-2.5 for the lower frequencies.  Something in the device model is zeroing out those frequencies in the output.
